# SignalR - try catch not working on Connection.Start()

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr, signalr.client

I have a wpf signalr Client with the code

```
public async Task<bool> StartConnection()
{
        try
        {
            await _connection.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Log($"Error:{Name}", ex);
            return false;
        }

        ....
}
```

but when the server is not running occurs an error and the application exit without pass on the try catch.

look what happens on visual studio debug

[visual studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0alvL.jpg)

Comment: Whats the (inner) stacktrace?

Comment: Need the inner stack trace to see the inner exception. Just a wild guess here, are you sure your `_connection` instance is not null?

Comment: how can i see the inner stacktrace?

Comment: _connection is not null, i do this "_connection = new HubConnection(Url);" on this class constructor

Comment: There´s no enough information to solve your issue. You should provide the code causing null reference exception